# OS X Webserver server does not work

Tags: macos, webserver

Here is the story. Somehow the spotlinght does not work, called apple support. The conclusion after 2 hour conversation is to clean reinstall the system. I did that and restored everything using time machine.

BUT, the webserver  does not work. If can still turn on the web server. But a browser can not load the page. Scanning the port of the server, seems ports 80 and 443 are not even detected. Any one knows how to solve it?

```
Port Scan has started…

Port Scanning host: 

Open TCP Port: 22     ssh
Open TCP Port: 88     kerberos
Open TCP Port: 311    asip-webadmin
Open TCP Port: 445    microsoft-ds
Open TCP Port: 464    kpasswd
Open TCP Port: 548    afpovertcp
Open TCP Port: 625    dec_dlm
Open TCP Port: 631    ipp
Open TCP Port: 749    kerberos-adm
Open TCP Port: 3306   mysql
Port Scan has completed…
```

Comment: OSX is 10.8.5 The server app is 2.2.2

Comment: I've been trying to do this too. The difference in my problem is that browser works just fine, but port scanner fails if the server is not launched with sudo.